# Prevent orientation change in touch devices with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I am developing a mobile web app. Is it possible to prevent orientation change? I want only portrait view. I was looking for some JavaScript solution, but could not find one. I am just using jQuery (no jQuery mobile). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because changing the orientation is a OS-thing, I don't think that this is possible - maybe the resize event gets triggered and you could do some things ...
But why don't you let the user decide?

Comment: For some reason I can't let the user to decide. I was also wondering if it's possible by HTML meta tags or something that.